# reledmac and reledpar fails with error (Missing number, treated as zero)

Tags: luatex, reledmac, reledpar

I'm trying to print two sections beside one another with the "reledmac" and "reledpar" packages.

However, the following error is returned thru lualatex:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
\l@dLcolrawbox1 
l.18   \begin{Leftside}
```

Is there a command that I'm missing?  Here's a MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.xmpdata}
    \Title{Sacrat\'issimum}
    \Author{M.}
    \Language{es}
    \Keywords{Rosa}
    \Publisher{}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[b6paper, 10pt, twoside, openright, final]{memoir}
\setlrmarginsandblock{1.25cm}{.5cm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{1.5cm}{*}{1}
\checkandfixthelayout{}

\usepackage[]{reledmac}
\usepackage[]{reledpar}

\usepackage[x-1a]{pdfx}

\begin{document}
\begin{pairs}
  \begin{Leftside}
    \beginnumbering
      \pstart
        \section{Prologo}
        \input{capitulo_a1}
      \pend
    \endnumbering
  \end{Leftside}
  \begin{Rightside}
    \beginnumbering
      \pstart
        \section*{\centering Nota}
        \input{capitulo_a2}
      \pend
    \endnumbering
  \end{Rightside}
\end{pairs}
\Columns
\end{document}
```

Comment: I get no error when replacing your `\input`ed files with some text. So the problem is likely in those files that you've not shown.

Comment: I, like @mbert, get no error. Please edit your example so that we can help you find the problem: Copy as little text as necessary (from your `capitulo_a1.tex` into the MWE) to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Thanks to everyone, I fixed the code.  It was lacking the ```begin{document}``` environment.

Comment: 1. We dont have the input content, so we can't help
2. In any case YOU MUST NOT use section directly inside `\pstart`, you will get trouble (but not these one). You should either use `\ȩledesection` or optional argument of `pstart`